# Computer crawls when connected to switch but not router

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch

I just upgraded to GS605 Netgear gigabyte switches on my network, and I use Cat 5e cables, so I can use the gigabit Ethernet.

One of my Windows PCs seems to have a very slow connection. I see an active 1K link on the switch for this port, and Windows reports that the link is running at 1 Gbps, but the computer takes 3-5 minutes to load Amazon.com and has ping times on the order of 700 ms.

I have another Windows 8 PC that works perfectly fine, and I have a Mac mini which is also connected to the switch and works fine.

If I take the Ethernet cable from the messed up computer and connect it directly to the router (not the switch), it is fast again. However, connected to the router, I'm back to 100 Mbps speeds, not gigabit speeds.

---

`ipconfig` gives the following output:

- Hostname: my computer's hostname
- Node type: hybrid
- IP routing enabled: no
- WINS proxy enabled: no
- IP address: my computer's DHCP address
- MAC address: my computer's MAC address
- Default gateway: my router's IP
- DHCP server address: my router's address
- IPv6 address: something long (I'm not familiar with IPv6 addresses)
- Various tunneling adapters, which are all disabled

I have had other computers in the same port on the switch and they all work fine. I also plugged this computer into a different port and had the same problem. Netgear tech support wasn't helpful.

I actually have another switch of the same model, but when I replaced this one with that one, it had the same problem.

I confirmed gigabit speeds between two other computers, both connected to this switch, so it does work at those speeds. Those computers also have fast Internet.

I don't have any clones MAC addresses in my network, and as for logs.... the only place I can think is the log file from the router.  I didn't even think of that, the only other place would be event viewer within windows.

This computer dual boots Windows 7 and Windows 8, and has these issues in both OSes.

Comment: Do other computers connected to the _same_ point of the switch, by the _same_ cables, show the same problem? Do you perhaps have some machine on which there is a "cloned MAC" from this one on the net? I'm not familiar with the switch you mention, but perhaps there is a way to get logs or some performance measures out of the machine, perhaps by SNMP or a special connection? Perhaps there is some VLAN configuration in it? Anything interesting in /var/log/messsages? What does `ifconfig` tell you?

Comment: If the router's Ethernet ports are 100 Mbps, there is no possible way to get gigabit Internet speeds. Network traffic can go no faster than the slowest link, and if switch to router is 100 Mbps, switch to Internet is no faster. Moreover, your Internet connection will probably limit Internet speeds to much slower than 100 Mbps anyway.  In your setup, gigabit speeds would only apply when communicating with other computers using only the new switches (if the router is in between the computers, it'll be 100 Mbps max)

Comment: Yes your correct, the internet will not be any more than 100Mbps, but the in house network will be 1GBbps which is what im looking for. In house streaming of music, home videos, movies...etc. The affected computer doesn't do internet or in-house networking. Attempted to transfer a 500gig file and it estimated 5 hours, lol. bleh.....

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add, I tried a new cable and had the same problem.  I then rebooted all the network devices again.  Shut off the switch, router, left the 2 unplugged for about 1 minute.
Turned on the router, and then the switch.  Rebooted PC again into Windows 8... and saw a connection... started seeing certain online items go online... checked and presto i was online and set with a 1Gbps internal connection.

Appreciate all the attempted helps, the info was good and helped me come to the conclusion that I am just going to reboot everything.

Goodnight everyone.

-J